# Chrysler Town and Country Van Door

Tags: door, town-and-country

I have a 2009 Town and Country and the automatic van door will not open. At least one problem is a broken plastic part that holds the thin wire in place which pulls the door open. I am attaching a picture of this part (obviously this is the one on the other side that is not broken; the broken one ended up in pieces). I am hoping that I can simply replace this part, put the wire back in, and be good to go. If anyone can tell me what the part number is I would appreciate it; I cannot seem to track is down online. In addition, if anyone had the same problem and has any advice I would also appreciate that!

[image: Part I need]

Comment: I have the exact same problem, were you able to get the replacement part??

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find solution for it ??

Answer (score 2):

That's part of the track assembly. Unfortunately, you'll have to replace the whole assembly as that exact part isn't available by itself (maybe you can find it at a pull-it-yourself type of junkyard, but I imagine they'd want you to take the whole assembly). Most likely, that assembly will have to be purchased through Chrysler.

I've also been told that the assembly has to be programmed to work correctly once it's installed, but I can't confirm that as I've never changed one myself.

Answer (score 0):

Along with that commonly broken bracket, the wiring harness for the door is known to wear inside the plastic track and stop working. Replacement door wiring harnesses are available because of the frequency of the failure, but it's not hard to just replace the failed wires individually and probably cheaper at shop rate than the replacement harness.